# Invalid indirect reference in decodeIndirectRef when trying to convert C++ to Java

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm trying to convert some C++ objects to Java objects.
But I'm having a weird issue and I can't find out why it's happening.

What I'm doing is getting a list of C++ objects, create Java objects from it and add it to an ArrayList.

It used to work well until I add a new String (getCoordinates()) in my C++ object. Since then, it doesn't work anymore.

Here is my code :

```
    jobject convertCPPTripsToJobject_v2(JNIEnv *env, std::list<Trip> *trips_cpp) {

    // create an ArrayList
    jclass clsArrayList = env->FindClass("java/util/ArrayList");
    jmethodID methodIdInitArray = env->GetMethodID(clsArrayList, "<init>", "()V");
    jobject listTrips = env->NewObject(clsArrayList, methodIdInitArray);

    if (clsArrayList != 0) {
        // we get the id of the add method from the ArrayList
        jmethodID midArrayListAdd = env->GetMethodID(clsArrayList, "add", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z");
        if (midArrayListAdd != 0) {
            // create different Java object from the cpp list 
            for (auto trip_cpp : *trips_cpp) {
                // create a ParcourGreen object
                jclass clsParcour = env->FindClass("net/pompoc/greenui/modele/ParcourGreen");
                jmethodID methodIdInitParcour = env->GetMethodID(clsParcour, "<init>", "(IILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;FZLjava/lang/String;)V");

                jobject parcour = env->NewObject(clsParcour, methodIdInitParcour,
                    trip_cpp.getId(),
                    trip_cpp.getType(),
                    env->NewStringUTF(trip_cpp.getStartDate().c_str()),
                    env->NewStringUTF(trip_cpp.getEndDate().c_str()),
                    trip_cpp.getSteps(),
                    trip_cpp.getIsPostProcessed() ? JNI_TRUE : JNI_FALSE,
                    env->NewStringUTF(trip_cpp.getCoordinates().c_str())
                    );

                env->CallBooleanMethod(listTrips, midArrayListAdd, parcour);
            }
        }
    }

    return listTrips;
}
```

And I get the error :

```
Invalid indirect reference 0x00000000 in decodeIndirectRef
```

(It wasn't exactly 0x00000000 of course)

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

**EDIT**

Here is a bit more of my error message :

```
    11-24 16:20:44.863: W/dalvikvm(16337): Invalid indirect reference 0xbea54328 in decodeIndirectRef
    11-24 16:20:44.863: I/dalvikvm(16337): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
    11-24 16:20:44.863: I/dalvikvm(16337):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x41835ea0 self=0x417304c8
    11-24 16:20:44.863: I/dalvikvm(16337):   | sysTid=16337 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074065748
    11-24 16:20:44.863: I/dalvikvm(16337):   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=100 stm=42 core=0
    11-24 16:20:44.863: I/dalvikvm(16337):   at net.pompoc.greenui.modele.ParcourGreen.<init>(ParcourGreen.java:-1)
    11-24 16:24:36.289: E/dalvikvm(19526): VM aborting
    11-24 16:24:36.289: A/libc(19526): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00004c46 (code=-6), thread 19526 (com.greenui)
```

**EDIT 2**

After further investigations, it appears that this seems to be the cause of all my troubles :

```
jobject parcour = env->NewObject(clsParcour, methodIdInitParcour,
                trip_cpp.getId(),
                trip_cpp.getType(),
                env->NewStringUTF(trip_cpp.getStartDate().c_str()),
                env->NewStringUTF(trip_cpp.getEndDate().c_str()),
                trip_cpp.getSteps(),
                trip_cpp.getIsPostProcessed() ? JNI_TRUE : JNI_FALSE,
                ---> env->NewStringUTF(trip_cpp.getCoordinates().c_str()) <---
            );
```

Without this line, it works.
With it, it doesn't.

Comment: Can you enable CheckJNI mode?  That might give you more detailed diagnostics.  Also, you're at risk of overflowing the local references table if the list is large; you could avoid this by explicitly deleting the local references you're creating in the loop.  You should also move the FindClass and GetMethodID calls outside the loop -- they're expensive and don't need to be inside.

Comment: I tried to enable CheckJNI, but Logcat keeps telling me that CheckJNI is off.
I don't know if it will help you, but when I do "adb devices" in Terminal, I can see my device. And when I do it in "adb shell", I can't see it...